# Prob. 16, Chap. 1 in Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, analytic-geometry

Here is Prob. 16, Chap. 1 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> Suppose $k \geq 3$, $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^k$, $\vert \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y} \vert = d > 0$, and $r > 0$. Prove:
>
> (a) If $2r > d$, there are infinitely many $\mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{R}^k$ such that $$\vert \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{x} \vert = \vert \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{y} \vert = r.$$
>
> (b) If $2r = d$, there is exactly one such $\mathbf{z}$.
>
> (c) If $2r< d$, there is no such  $\mathbf{z}$.
>
> How must these statements be modified if $k$ is $2$ or $1$?

My work:

First of all, if an element $\mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{R}^k$ satisfies
$$\vert \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{x} \vert = \vert \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{y} \vert = r,$$
then we have
$$d = \vert \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y} \vert \leq \vert \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{x} \vert + \vert \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{y} \vert = 2r.$$
So if $2r < d$, then there is no such $\mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{R}^k$, as Rudin asserts in part (c).

Now let's take a real number $\alpha \in (0,1)$, let $\mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{R}^k$ be defined as $$\mathbf{z} \colon= (1 - \alpha) \mathbf{x} + \alpha \mathbf{y}.$$
Then
$$\vert \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{x} \vert = \alpha \vert \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y} \vert = \alpha d, $$
and
$$\vert \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{y} \vert = (1- \alpha) \vert \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y} \vert = (1-\alpha )d. $$
So we have
$$\vert \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{x} \vert = \vert \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{y} \vert = r$$
if and only if
$$\alpha d = (1-\alpha)d = r,$$
which holds if and only if
$$\alpha = \frac 1 2 \ \ \ \mbox{ and } \ \ \ r = \frac d 2.$$
So if $r = \frac d 2$, then the element $\mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{R}^k$ given by the formula $$ \mathbf{z} \colon= \frac 1 2 (\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y})$ satisfies our relation.

Moreover, if $r = \frac d 2$ and if some element $\mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{R}^k$ satisfies our equality, then?

Also, an element $\mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{R}^k$ satisfies
$$\vert \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{x} \vert = \vert \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{y} \vert = r$$
if and only if
$$\vert \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{x} \vert^2 = \vert \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{y} \vert^2 = r^2,$$
and the last relation in terms of components becomes
$$\sum_{j=1}^k (z_j- x_j)^2 = \sum_{j=1}^k (z_j - y_j)^2.$$
Hence
$$\sum_{j=1}^k (y_j - x_j) ( 2 z_j - x_j - y_j) = 0.$$

How do we use the fact that $k \geq 3$?

And, how do we modify these statements if $k$ is $1$ or $2$?

Comment: Look at the sphere of radius $r$ about $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$. For $k=2$, the intersection of these spheres (circles) contains at most two points. This is not the case for $k\geq 3$.

Comment: @SamM I'll appreciate if you could answer my question in rigorously and in more detail.